# How can I get the new array after unset?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I decoded json array. and unset the "N/A,'',-" from the array. When I print the array it shows me both unsetted result and previous original array. I need just unsetted array. how can I return this new array.

```
$root_arr = json_decode($data, true);

  function array_depth(array $array) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
          array_depth($value);
        }else{
          if(($value == "-") || ($value == "") || ($value == "N/A")){
            unset($array[$key]);
          }

        }
    }

   print_r(array_values($array));
   //return $array;
  }

array_depth($root_arr);
```

and this is the result:
[array result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urbbb.png)

Comment: It's a recursive action, so of course it will show you a dump within every call. And if you want to alter the original array, you need to pass it by reference, because functions work with copies, not the original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the function to pass `$array` by reference `&` and don't return anything.
Also, expose the `$value` as a reference so that it is updated:

```
function array_depth(array &$array) {
    foreach ($array as $key => &$value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            array_depth($value);
        } else {
            if(($value == "-") || ($value == "") || ($value == "N/A")){
                unset($array[$key]);
            }
        }
    }
}

array_depth($root_arr);
print_r($root_arr);
```

Comment: I tried your solution, it did not work. It gives me the original array.

Comment: Sorry, forgot `&$value` in the loop. https://3v4l.org/mPorI

Comment: Awesome. Thanks man. But can you explain why we using "&$value". Because $array is already taking as reference like "&$array". By the way thank you.

Comment: `foreach` makes a copy of the array and loops that, so when you pass `$value` recursively it doesn't modify the original array.  Using a reference updates the original array.